# Ajax and Google charts. Passing PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

exampleUsingPHP.html

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsonData = $.ajax({
url: "getData.php",
//dataType:"java",
async: false
//success: function(results) {alert(results);}
}).responseText;


// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
alert(jsonData);
// Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

 // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>

<script>
</script>  
</html>
```

getData.php

```
   <?php 
   echo "[['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
   ['Work',     11],
   ['Eat',      2],
   ['Commute',  2],
   ['Watch TV', 2],
   ['Sleep',    7]
   ]";
   ?>
```

So my problem is the line...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

When I try to pass jsonData into the arrayToDataTable(), it does not like that it is a string. What can I do to convert the string "jsonData" into valid javascript that can be used in the arrayToDataTable() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could just use the function `json_encode()` for stress free results. Create an array of your values (of course build like the one that is needed for it to fit for google chart), then use the function. [**Sample Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fcFXjy)

PHP (getData.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['get_chart'])) {
    $values = array(
        array('Task', 'Hours Per Day'),
        array('Work', 11),
        array('Eat', 2),
        array('Commute', 2),
        array('Watch TV', 2),
        array('Sleep', 7),
    );

    echo json_encode($values);
    exit;
}
```

HTML/jQuery

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(load_chart_data);

function load_chart_data() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getData.php', // provide correct url
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_chart: true},
        dataType: 'JSON', // <-- since youre expecting JSON
        success: function(chart_values) {
            console.log(chart_values); // take a peek on the values (browser console)
            draw_chart(chart_values); // call your drawing function!
        }
    });
}

function draw_chart(chart_values) {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chart_values);
    var options = {
        title: 'Your super chart!',
        vAxis: {title: 'Hours Per Day', titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
        hAxis: {title: 'Task', titleTextStyle: {italic: false}},
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. You solved my nightmare.

Comment: @JamesPiekarz sure no prob

Comment: this chart is not dynamically changed. when 'getData.php' set to blank the same chart always displaying

Comment: And also there is no proper way to 'GET' values from MySql data table

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a valid json.
Right now, If you paste your returned String to jsonlint, you can see it is invalid json.

To check the validtity of the json object, you can use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

create json from php code - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

eg of valid json string:

```
{
    "Work": 11,
    "Eat": 2
}

var myJSONString = // your JSON string
var jsobj= JSON.parse(myJSONString);
```